How to consume kafka messages from offset 0 in the startup of the my spring boot application whenever my service restarts
I want to consume all the kafka messages from 0 offset in startup of my spring boot application whenever my service restart. Below is my kafka configuration but it is not working.
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String,String> consumerFactory1(){
    Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    InetAddress ip = null;
    try {
        ip = getIPAddress();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error on getting local host", e.getMessage());
    }
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            kafkaserver);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
            (ip != null? ip.getHostName() : "rasbrandmapper-" + UUID.randomUUID()));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}

private InetAddress getIPAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost();
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> configKafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory1());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    return factory;
}




@KafkaListener(id = "config_id", topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "#{@kafkaConstants.getConfig()}",
        partitionOffsets = {@PartitionOffset(partition = "0-11", initialOffset = "0")}),
        containerFactory = "configKafkaListenerContainerFactory1")`your text`


Setting ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to earliest only takes effect the first time the consumer starts in that consumer group. Because its value is earliest, when the consumer starts, it will start from the earliest offset on the topic partition, whereas if you set it to latest, it starts from the latest available offset on the partition.
In order to start from a particular offset, each time you start the application, you need to seek to that offset programmatically. See the ref docs on this topic here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/seek.html
